# Substring string column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, jira-rest-api

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns : ticket number and history.

History is a string with the following structure. I need to create third column which include author name who change status from New to Open. Is it possible?

```
[
                {
                    "id": "1,
                    "author": {
                        "name": "user1",
                        "emailAddress": "user1@test.com",
                        "displayName": "user1"
                    },
                    "created": "2021-06-09T12:54:22.915+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "field": "name",
                            "from": "1",
                            "fromString": null,
                            "to": "2",
                            "toString": "test"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "author": {
                       
                        "name": "user2",
                        "emailAdress": "user2@test.com",                       
                        "displayName": "user2"                          
                    },
                    "created": "2021-06-11T09:33:18.692+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "field": "status",
                            "from": 3,
                            "fromString": "New",
                            "to": "7",
                            "toString": "Open"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
```

Comment: Hey Welcome to stackoverflow, please post what you have tried already... Take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/tour 

Your answer can easily be obtained by traversing the JSON (I assume).  You could achieve it by anonymous functions like df['this_new_column'] = df['History_Column'].apply(lambda x: your_func(x)), Process the input x  in your_func() as you wish.

Comment: What do you expect as output? Can you give the result of your sample please?

Comment: Output should be 2 columns : Ticket Number (example: ticket1), UserName (example: user2).   UserName should be computed from history (when field = 'status', fromString = 'New',  toString = 'Open')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is named `df`, the history column (column 2) is named `history` and the items in the history column actually are json strings with a structure like the one you've provided, you could do the following:

```
import json

def extract_author(json_string):
    records = json.loads(json_string)
    for record in records:
        items = record['items'][0]
        if (items['field'] == 'status'
            and items['fromString'] == 'New'
            and items['toString'] == 'Open'):
            return record['author']['name']
    return None

df['author'] = df['history'].map(extract_author)
```